# Rotate rect around axis in D3 graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to get a rectangle with four handles on all corners to rotate the `rect` in angle needed. Could someone assist me with how I would go about rotating the `rect` on its axis on the drag of the handles?

I did find an example which is for an `ellipse` and I tried modifying it for a `rect` but was not successful.

```
var w = 400,
    h = 400,
    data = {
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        rx: 50,
        ry: 50,
        angle: 0
    };

// Returns radians
function angleBetweenPoints(p1, p2) {
    if (p1[0] == p2[0] && p1[1] == p2[1])
        return Math.PI / 2;
    else
        return Math.atan2(p2[1] - p1[1], p2[0] - p1[0] );
}

function distanceBetweenPoints(p1, p2) {
    return Math.sqrt( Math.pow( p2[1] - p1[1], 2 ) + Math.pow( p2[0] - p1[0], 2 ) );
}

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 300);

var group = svg.append("svg:g").attr('id' , 'id123');


var handles = group.selectAll("circle")
        .data([
            {x:data.x, y:data.y + data.ry, name:"n"},
            {x:data.x + data.rx, y:data.y, name:"e"},
            {x:data.x, y:data.y - data.ry, name:"s"},
            {x:data.x - data.rx, y:data.y, name:"w"}
        ], function (d) { return d.name; })
        .enter()
        .append("svg:circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", 6.5)
        .call(d3.behavior.drag()
            .on("drag", function (d) {
                // Resizing

                var exy = [d3.event.x, d3.event.y],
                    dxy = [data.x, data.y],
                    dist = distanceBetweenPoints(exy, dxy),
                    angle = data.angle + angleBetweenPoints(dxy, exy);
                switch(d.name) {
                    case "e":
                    case "w":
                        break;
                    case "s":
                    case "n":
                        angle += Math.PI/2;
                        break;
                };
                data.angle = angle;
                update();
            })
        );

var ellipse = group.append("svg:ellipse");

function toDegrees(rad) {
    return rad * (180/Math.PI);
}

function update() {
    ellipse
        .attr("cx", data.x)
        .attr("cy", data.y)
        .attr("rx", data.rx)
        .attr("ry", data.ry);

    group.attr("transform", "rotate(" + toDegrees(data.angle) + "," + data.x + "," + data.y + ")");

}

update();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/roug3/hon4kxp6/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you make a rectangle

```
var rect = group.append("svg:rect");
```

Then place the rectangle accordingly.

```
//place the rectangle in its place
function update() {
    rect
        .attr("x", data.x - data.rx +5)//the x coordinate
        .attr("y", data.y  - data.ry +5)
        .attr("width", (data.rx*2)-10)//the width
        .attr("height", (data.ry*2)-10);//the height

    group.attr("transform", "rotate(" + toDegrees(data.angle) + "," + data.x + "," + data.y + ")");

}
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/hon4kxp6/3/)

Working code of a rectangle rotation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/hon4kxp6/4/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Cyril . That should help me :)

Comment: Cyril , One other thing if i add a drag on the group the click handlers dont seem to work . Also can this be made into a drag and rotate at the same time ?